# How to clear cache in safari Web Driver using Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to clear Safari's cache when using Selenium WebDriver.

My test cases execute correctly the first time, but the second time Safari opens to the page where the previous session ended.

Is there a solution?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  Are you seeing an old version of a file; or, are you finding that you are still logged into a previous browsing session (e.g., a PHP session?)

Comment: Whenever I launch my browser it's already logged in. Because cache memory was not cleared. So I want to clear cache using Java code or browser settings permanently so that it will launch new fresh browser everytime. I am using version 8 of safari for webdriver

Comment: When you say "logged in", that makes me think of a PHP session. In which case, you would need to clear your cookies, not the cache.